# How to make View > Show > Layer Edges on by default?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I always enable the layer edges in Photoshop, since it disables after I close Photoshop.

```
View > Show > Layer Edges
```

Is there any way to let it always on?

Comment: Try setting it with **no document open**. Then close and relaunch the app.

Comment: That option is disabled with no document open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can somehow set it on by default, but you can use Script Events Manager to tell Photoshop to click the menu item every time a document is created or opened.

1. First we need an action that'd enable the menu item (make sure you
   have any document opened for the option to be available). To create it navigate to `Window >
   Actions`, create a new `Set` or use any existing ones and click
   `Create New Action` button

   [image]
2. Give it a name and in the flyout menu select `Insert Menu Item`.

   [image]
3. Find the `Layer Edges` in the Photoshop menu, click it, it'll be
   added as a step to the action. Click `Stop` in the bottom of the
   panel to stop recording. The action will look like this:

   [image]
4. Navigate to `File > Scripts > Scripts Event Manager`, enable the
   manager if it's disabled, in the bottom select your Action, in the
   events menu select `New Document` and click `Add`. Then repeat for
   `Open Document` event.

   [image]

That's it. Every time you open a document or create a new one this action that selects a menu item will be called.

Comment: It's working, thanks!